# Reset tableoutput with action button in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I have an shinydashboard app, the app get an filter box and a tabset which show a datatatable depending on filter.
I have a reset button which reset the filters whith shinyjs::reset function, and I want to reset also the tableset and showing the complete table or nothing.
I want also to do it for a valuboxes.

My app is like this :

For server interface I have an basic : `output$tableprint_A <- DT::renderDataRable ({})`
ui :

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    #### First tab item #####
    tabItem(tabName = "fpc",
            fluidRow(
              infoBoxOutput("kpm_inf", width = 6),
              infoBoxOutput(outputId = "fpc_inf", width = 6)
            ),
            fluidRow(
              box(title = "Variables filter",
                  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                  id = "side_panel",
                  br(),
                  background = "light-blue",
                  solidHeader = TRUE,
                  width = 2,
                  selectInput("aaa", "aaa", multiple = T, choices = c("All", as.character(unique(fpc$aaa))))
                  br(),
                  br(),
                  p(class = "text-center", div(style = "display:inline-block", actionButton("go_button", "Search", 
                                                                                            icon = icon("arrow-circle-o-right"))),
                    div(style = "display:inline-block", actionButton("reset_button", "Reset", 
                                                                     icon = icon("repeat")))),
                  p(class = 'text-center', downloadButton('dl_fpc', 'Download Data'))),
              tabBox(
                title = tagList(),
                id = "tabset1",
                width = 10,
                tabPanel(
                  "A \u2030 ",
                  DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint_A"),
                  bsModal(id = 'startupModal', title = 'Update message', trigger = '',
                          size = 'large',
                          tags$p(tags$h2("Last update of A : 01/09/2017",
                                         br(), br(),
                                         "Last update of B : 01/09/2017",
                                         br(), br(),
                                         "Last update of C : 01/09/2017",
                                         style = "color:green", align = "center")))
                ),
                tabPanel(
                  "B % Table",
                  DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint_B")),
                type = "pills"
              )
            ),
            fluidRow(
              # Dynamic valueBoxes
              valueBoxOutput("info_gen", width = 6)
            )
```

I tried this :

```
  observeEvent(input$reset_button, {
    output$tableprint_A <- NULL
  })
```

Edit:

I want something like that, but when I action the search button I want it to appear again :

```
 shinyjs::onclick("reset_button",
                   shinyjs::toggle(id = "tableprint_A", anim = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this out:

```
output$tableprint_A <- renderDataTable({
  if(input$reset_button == 1) {
    NULL
  }else{
    datatable(...)
  }
})
```

if the button is clicked then nothing will be displayed, else the `datatable` is shown.

**[EDIT]**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(selectInput("select", "select", choices = unique(iris$Species), multiple = T),
                 actionButton("go_button", "Search", 
                              icon = icon("arrow-circle-o-right")),
                 actionButton("reset_button", "Reset", 
                              icon = icon("repeat")),
                              DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {

    values <- reactiveValues(matrix = NULL)

    observe({
      if (input$go_button == 0)
        return()
      values$matrix <- iris[iris$Species %in% input$select, ]
    })
    observe({
      if (input$reset_button == 0)
        return()
      values$matrix <- NULL
    })

    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(values$matrix, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE))}
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you it's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: Not exactly, it's works just 1 time when I do a new filter it's showing nothing

Comment: Can you explain what does it mean: when i do a new filter?

Comment: When I filter my table after clicking on reset_button it's not giving me a new table but NULL

Comment: The reset button is cleaning the filter box and the datatable, but when I want do do show the table with a new filter it's giving nothing in output